# How to initialize recursively a class inheriting of list?

Tags: python, inheritance, recursion

My aim is to code an object similar to `numpy.array` from scratch using the builtin `list`.

I begin by creating a class `Array` inheriting of `list`.

I got stuck on the initialization. If I only want to handle 1-dimension arrays, there is nothing to do, I keep the `__init__` method of `__list__`. The problem come from higher dimensions.

```
class Array(list):
    pass # no __init__ method, we keep the method from list
```

It does this:

```
>>> a = Array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> isinstance(a, Array) # expect True
True
>>> isinstance(a[0], Array) # expect True
False
```

Then I tried the following:

```
class Array(list):

    def __init__(self, l):
        if l == [] or all(not isinstance(x, list) for x in l):
            self = l
        else:
            assert(all(isinstance(x, list) for x in l))
            self = Array(Array(x) for x in l)
```

But it does not work:

```
>>> a = Array([1, 2])
>>> a # expect [1, 2]
[]
```

I understand why the previous codes do not work. The first one do not call the array initialization method on the sublists and the second one override `self` locally (but it does not have any effect outside the scope of the `__init__` function).

My question is how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
class Array(list):

    def __init__(self, l):

        def a(x):
            if isinstance(x, list):
                return Array([a(y) for y in x])
            return x

        if isinstance(l, list):
            self.extend(a(x) for x in l)
        else:
            self.append(l)

z = Array([1,[2,[3]]])
assert isinstance(z, Array)
assert isinstance(z[1], Array)
assert isinstance(z[1][1], Array)
```

You might want to extend this to support generic iterables, not just lists.

Comment: Thanks, it works well. I did as you said: I replaced `isinstance(x, list)` by `hasattr(x, '__iter__')`.